# find specific string in array index and get matching values

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to get the indices from an array in which 'Type_' matches from the array.

The array is like this:

```
['Type_test', 'Type_hello', 'Type_google', 'Type_apple', 'mango', 'orange'];
```

and the answer should be like this:

```
['Type_test', 'Type_hello', 'Type_google', 'Type_apple'];
```

Comment: just [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
const array = ['Type_test', 'Type_hello', 'Type_google', 'Type_apple', 'mango', 'orange'];
const result = array.filter(e => e.startsWith('Type_'));
console.log(result);
```

The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function takes a predicate function and returns a new array with only the items that satisfy the predicate. If the function returns a truthy value, the element will be kept, and vice-versa. For every element in the array, the predicate function will be called with the current element, the index of the current element, and the array.

This code retrieves the elements of `array` that start with `Type_`. In other words, it filters the array so that every element `e` satisfies the condition `e.startsWith('Type_')`.

Comment: `filter()` is not an ES6 feature, only the arrow function usage is